# equation of the tangent of the curve at the given point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, graphing-functions, tangent-line

I am stuck at this. Any help will be much appreciated.

> Given $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}$,
>
> 1. Draw the graph of $f$.
> 2. Find the equation of the tangent to the graph of $f$ at the given point $M(2,f(2))$ and draw its graph.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Start by calculating $f'(2)$, which gives the slope of the line. Then you will have the slope and a point on the line, which is enough to find the equation.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJoy8nHKwRc      this link can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll leave it to you to draw the graph.  Notice the derivative:

$$f'(2)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac2{2+h}-1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-h}{h(2+h)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-1}{2+h}=-\frac12$$

And equation of a line tangent to a point $(2,f(2))$ is given by

$$y-f(2)=f'(2)(x-2)$$

Comment: Thanks so much I could not think of the right equation!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @EleonoraDiamantiJaniSali No problem!  Glad to help :D

Answer (score 1):

differentiate to get 
$$f'(x)=2lnx$$
then use the general equation of a line:
$$\frac{y-y(1)}{x-x(1)}=(slope.of .tangent)$$

Comment: You integrated.

Answer (score 0):

First, we evaluate the derivative $f'(2)$.
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{x}$$
Hence,
$$f'(x)=-\frac{2}{x^2}$$
Therefore:
$$f'(2)=-\frac{2}{4}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Hence, the gradient of the tangent at $x=2$ is $m=-\frac{1}{2}$.

The equation of a straight line (the tangent in this case) is given by $y=mx+c$.

Substitute the values of $m$, then substitute $y$ and $x$ of your point $(2, f(2))$ to evaluate the value of $c$ to align your tangent to the curve.

Hence,

$$f(2)=-\frac{1}{2} \times 2+c \tag{1}$$

Evaluating $f(2)$:

$$f(2)=\frac{2}{2}=1$$

Hence, we evaluate $c$ by rearranging equation $(1)$.

$$1=-1+c$$
$$c=2$$

Hence, the equation of your tangent is:

$$y=-\frac{1}{2} x+2$$

In an alternative form:

$$x+2y=4$$

I assume you know how to plot graphs.

If you have any doubts or questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: yes i can draw the graph its just that for the past few days I 've  studied so much algebra that my  brain is fried! thanks so much! 

Answer (score 0):

### [image: tangent]

**Goal**

Given the function
$$
 f(x) = \frac{2}{x}
$$
and the value $x_{*} = 2$, find
$$
  y = mx + b,
$$
the equation of the line tangent to $f(x)$ at $x_{*} = 2$.

**Strategy**

1. The slope of the tangent line is given by $m = f'(x_{*})$.
2. Use the slope-intercept equation $f(x_{*}) = m x_{*} + b$ to find $b$.

**Slope $m$**

Compute the derivative function
$$
  f'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^2}.
$$
Compute the slope at this location
$$
 f'(x_{*}) = -\frac{2}{x_{*}^2} = -\frac{1}{2}
$$

**Intercept $b$**

Use the slope intercept form $y=mx+b$ to find $b$. We can use any point $(x,f(x))$, but we already have the point $(x,f(x))$.
$$
 f(x_{*}) = m x_{*} + b \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad b = 2
$$

**Solution**
$$
  y = mx + b = -\frac{1}{2} x + 3
$$